# GitHub security alerts

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I got an email from GitHub stating that one of my project's dependencies "hoek" had a known security vulnerability and I should update it. However, hoek itself is not something I installed but is a dependency of one of my other dependencies. Is there anything I can do about this or does the maintainer of the project that uses hoek have to update the version they use?

Comment: you could fork / clone the dependency, upload it to npm, then do the same for the parent dependency in order to consume the new child dependency. I'd start by making an issue in the child dependency's GitHub repo (if one exists) first though...

Comment: There are a few options. Is there a new release of your direct dependency that depends on a fixed version of `hoek`?

Answer (score 0):

The package CVE-2018-3728 is vulnerable. The vulnerable versions of hoek are prior to 4.2.1 and 5.0.3  and are vulnerable to prototype pollution.
The affected versions of hoek are until version 5.0.2,  The remediation is to update to version 4.2.1, 5.0.3 or later.
For more information, you can view the fix pull request here: https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/pull/231/commits/5aed1a8c4a3d55722d1c799f2368857bf418d6df